# How can I run a specific line as a command in a text file?

Tags: bash, command-line

Sometimes I need to exec a single command which is in a shell script.

I already know `sed -n 'line_num p'` can print that line. But how can I exec that printed out specific line as a command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -n 'line_num p' | bash
```

or, if the command does not contain whitespace,

```
"$(sed -n 'line_num p')"
```

Comment: @mikeserv I'm interested in knowing the context of that statement for my own education.

Comment: No need to put a space between `line_num` and `p`, so for example if `line_num` is 123, then you can `sed -n 123p | bash`. And if `sh` is enough, then just use `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: So, `sed -n 'line_num p' | sh` could be another solution? Is this one has more compatibility?

Comment: @Zen - that depends on what shell is targeted for the script. It also depends on what shell `sh` actually is. On Debian *(and derived)* systems `sh` is usually `dash`. If the script is written for `dash` *(or otherwise relies on portable syntax)* then probably, yeah, but if it is written for `bash` then almost definitely not.

Comment: could this be done with the history file so that if I run `history` and I see that I want to run line 900, can I run line 900 somehow?

Comment: For those not that experienced with `sed` (like myself), it might be helpful to clarify where the name of the text file goes in this command, though maybe I'm misunderstanding the original question.

Comment: Second option `"$(sed -n 123p file_with_commands.txt)"` doens't work for me. It seems to interpret the whole line as a single command name, for example if line is `echo Hello`, bash looks for the command named `echo hello` as a whole.

Comment: How can I improve first option to also print the line before bashing? One way is `cmd=$(sed -n 123p file_with_commands.txt) && echo $cmd && bash -c "$cmd"`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing this interactively, you could write the line into the bash history:

```
history -s "$(sed -n 'line_num p')"
```

Then press <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert the line into the readline buffer, and execute it; that gives you a chance to glance at the line before it's too late.

Comment: Thats pretty clever, and probably a good assumption.

Comment: what does this -s option mean here? I can't find explanations in `man history`

Comment: @zen: `history` is a built-in, so it is documented in `help history` (or `man bash`, but that's a lot of reading). Quoting the above, `history -s` will "append the ARGs to the history list as a single entry"

Answer (score 2):

You can do...

```
{ head -n"$((NUM-1))"; IFS= read -r line; } </path/to/script >/dev/null
eval "$line"
```

That will get only the `$NUM` line from your script in the shell variable `$line` and then evaluate it as a command in the current shell.

Another way to do this could look like:

```
 </path/to/script sed "${NUM}q;d" >/tmp/"$$"
 . /tmp/"$$" ; rm /tmp/"$$"
```

Comment: 'eval' is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If eval is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: Yup. Everybody loves `eval`.

Comment: `gnu sed` has the `e` flag so something like `sed "${NUM}"'!d;s/^//e;q'` would also work

Answer (score 2):

Are you editing your script with vim (vi on Linux)?
In vi add a mapping:

```
:nmap <F4> Y:!<C-R>"<C-H><CR>
```

and afterwards when you are on the interesting line in vi press F4

Answer (score -2):

In bash you can run the following command:

```
for line in $(cat file.txt); do command $line; done
```