# How to Hide PID and Exit Status When Running a Background Command in Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, io-redirection

I have a text file that has over a hundred lines, each of which is an **sh** command:

```
echo foo
...
echo bar
```

I'm looking for an **sh** command that I can invoke from a terminal which will run the command from said file associated with a specified line number. I do not want the terminal to show the usual system-related content that is normally associated with commands run in a terminal.

For example, if I use something like `xdotool type "$(sed -n 1p file)" &` (note that I'm open to a more elegant command),

I get the following terminal output:

```
[1] 9531
user@host:~$ echo foo
```

**I wish to suppress the `[1] 9531` line.** Please keep in mind, however, that I do *not* wish to suppress the **echo bar** line, as that is where I have a chance to verify that I'm about to execute the desired command and not something else. Nor do I wish for any text to be displayed to the left of the command prompt.

I then hit the <**Enter**> key of my keyboard and get:

```
foo
[1]+  Done                    xdotool type "$(sed -n 1p file)" &
user@host:~$
```

**I wish to suppress the `[1]+  Done...` line.**

How can I suppress the terminal output of said two lines? I've tried every redirect scheme I can find, with no joy.

Comment: @Quasímodo I have a long, manual procedure that I run about every two years or so. Scattered throughout said procedure, I have about a hundred or so bash commands (some quite lengthy) that are run from a terminal emulator. Instead of typing in a particular command when it is called for, I have copied all of said commands to a text file. I then just have to run the `xdotool...` command as shown in the OP, changing just the line number (goes a lot quicker). The output I want to suppress just gets in the way when I am running said procedure...

Comment: So it seems you want to run commands from some lines of the text file? If yes, can you update your question with that?

Comment: @Quasímodo That is correct.

Comment: @Quasímodo I definitely want a chance to check each particular command before executing same (I have added a sentence to the OP to emphasize this). [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178800/144299) answer in your link does a pretty nice job, but with an extra key stroke I'd like to avoid...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116739/discussion-between-quasimodo-and-digger).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to simplify, what you are seeing is the normal output when you run a command in the background (`&` symbol). One can see the same if one runs this simplified version:

```
ls &
```

To avoid seeing that output, you can sorround your command with parenthesis:

```
(ls &)
```

Or, in your case

```
(xdotool type "$(sed -n 1p file)" &)
```

In your particular case, it doesn't seem you really need the `&`, so it may be easier to remove it from your command:

```
xdotool type "$(sed -n 1p file)"
```

**PS**

If you want to run all the file sequentially from beginning to end, you might prefer doing something like

```
x=0
```

and then, for each line, run

```
x=$((x+1)); (xdotool type "$(sed -n "${x}p" file)" &)
```

This way you don't need to modify the number each time.

Also have a look at this:
[How to interactively run all commands in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622264/443734)

Comment: That works well!

Comment: Actually, I'll keep the "&", since it prevents the command from being repeated to the left of the command prompt...

Comment: To summarize, the best solution for me (so far) is: `(xdotool type "$(sed -n 1p file)" &)`

Comment: Suggestions? I think you're correct, but I'm struggling with a suitable title...

Comment: To summarize, the best solution for me (so far) is: `(x=1; xdotool type "$(sed -n "${x}p" file)" &)`.

Comment: What about this?: `x=$((x+1)); (xdotool type "$(sed -n "${x}p" file)" &)`. This way you don't need to modify the number each time. Just make `x=0` before the first time.

Comment: That could be a real time-saver for a scheme like mine...please add it to your very excellent answer!

Comment: Have a look at this: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622264/443734]. This is a real time-saver