# How to interactively run all commands in a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command

I have a text file `commands.txt` that has over a hundred lines, each of which is a shell command:

```bsh
echo foo
...
echo bar
```

I want to run each line in the file, but I would like to check each line just before running it. Besides, some lines have generic code like

```bsh
ping <dest_host>
```

Where I am expected to write an appropriate word for the command.
I am trying to find an easy way to run all of these commands in order. Running it like if it were a script is not an option, and copy pasting each line will be a bit tedious.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do commands in this file set variables that are used later in the file, and does the file contain multi-line commands, or compound commands and pipelines?

Comment: sounds like a job for the DEBUG trap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a script named `carefully_run.sh` with these contents:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                                
                                                                               
while IFS= read -r -u3 cmd
do
    read -e -i "$cmd" -p "$USER $ " cmd
    eval "$cmd"
done 3<$1
```

Then you just need to run

```
carefully_run.sh commands.txt
```

For each line in `commands.txt` it will present you a prompt with the contents of the line already written. Then you will have a chance to inspect and modify it however you want, and when you press enter, it will run the command. Then it will present you the next one.

Note:

If `commands.txt` contains a line like

```
foo=bar
```

The value of `foo` will be preserved while running the commands in `commands.txt`, but it will be lost after the last one. If you need to preserve it, and you happen to be running `bash`, you can achieve that by running

```bsh
source carefully_run.sh commands.txt
```

Instead of

```bsh
./carefully_run.sh commands.txt
```

Comment: To read each line verbatim, you have to `while IFS= read -r -u3 cmd`. Will xdotool give the user a chance to edit the line first? Maybe this is needed: `IFS= read -p "$USER $ " -i "$cmd" -r -e newcmd && eval "$newcmd"`

Comment: `xdotool` will just type the command to the console, but it will not "press enter". The user will still be able to edit the line before running

Comment: OK, so `read -i ... -e` is certainly an alternative.

Comment: How could we correctly handle the case where a line contains something like `echo "foo\nbar"`? One could except to show `foo` in a line and `bar` in the next one, but this is not what happens.

Comment: Also, any ideas on how to implement the same on `zsh` ?. I don't find any `-i` and `-p` equivalents in the man pages

Comment: I recommend you ask a followup question so you can add the zsh tag and attract top zsh users.

Comment: Okay, done. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/622434/443734)

Comment: Similar idea in this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/621863/144299