# How to interactively run all commands in a file in zsh?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, command

I came across [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/622263/443734). It asks for a way to interactively run all commands in a file.

One answer proposed using a `bash` script like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                                
                                                                               
while IFS= read -r -u3 cmd
do
    read -e -i "$cmd" -p "$USER $ " cmd
    eval $cmd
done 3<$1
```

I was wondering if the same could be achieved using `zsh`, since I would like to `source` the script so that I can keep variables declared in the file.

Comment: `print -z foo`, for any expression foo, seems to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
run_carefully() {
  # Take the first arg as a file name, read the file and split it on newlines.
  local cmd; for cmd in ${(f)"$(<$1)"}; do
    # Let the user edit (or delete) the command, before evaluating it.
    vared cmd
    eval "$cmd"
  done
}
```

Alternatively, we could let the user edit the entire list of commands before running it all at once:

```bsh
run_all_carefully() {
  # Take the first arg as a file name and read the file.
  local list="$(<$1)"

  # Let the user edit the list of commands, before evaluating it.
  vared list
  eval "$list"
}
```

Note that in both cases, <kbd>Enter</kbd> will accept the entire edit, whereas <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a newline without exiting the editor. For the second case, where all commands are edited at once, you might want to set up your own keymap (passed to vared with the `-M` option) where you swap these two around.

Documentation:

- [Command substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution) (`$(<foo)`)
- [Parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) (`${(f)"$(foo)"}`)
- [Built-in command `vared`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared)