# How can i run specific lines from a file as commands in the shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I am basing my question on the thread here: [How can I run a specific line as a command in a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178656/how-can-i-run-a-specific-line-as-a-command-in-a-text-file)

How do I run *a set of lines* from the the text file?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
Input file:
      1 #!/usr/bin/csh -v
      2
      3 date
      4
      5 echo "abc"
      6
      7 set cell="bananas"
      8
      9   set cmd = "echo apples \
     10               oranges \
     11               graped $cell"
     12
     13 echo $cmd
     14

sed -n '5,13 p' /tmp/1 | sh
```

gives:

```
abc
(blank line)
```

Why doesn't this execute the rest of the lines? Or as I suspect, is it running it but not giving any output since these commands are run in a new? sh(ell) everytime and not in a single shell session?

Thanks!

Comment: I would strongly urge you to read [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) to see why using `csh` as a scripting language (it is fine as a shell) is a very bad idea.

Comment: @terdon will do. Thank you. my intent here is simply to have frequently used c-shell commands and/or 1-liner scripts saved into a text file that I can re-use whenever needed to avoid typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test is failing because you’re using a different shell, `sh`, instead of the shell expected by the script, `csh`.

```
sed -n 5,13p /tmp/1 | csh
```

will produce the results you expect.